# I have gotten a Room DB implementation does not exist in Android Kotlin MVVM Room app

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, dagger-hilt

I am trying to convert a tutorial I found that uses Kotlin, RxJava, Hilt and Room into an app that uses Kotlin and Coroutines.  I have gotten several errors in the process of trying to make it work.  These latest one appears to be a Room error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.pokemon, PID: 17322
> java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.pokemonkotlin.db.PokemonDB. PokemonDB_Impl does not exist
> at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:97)
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:1486)
> at com.example.pokemonkotlin.db.PokemonDB$Companion.getAppDB(PokemonDB.kt:25)
> at com.example.pokemonkotlin.di.DBModule.providePokemonDB(DBModule.kt:23)
> at com.example.pokemonkotlin.di.DBModule_ProvidePokemonDBFactory.providePokemonDB(DBModule_ProvidePokemonDBFactory.java:37)
> at com.example.pokemonkotlin.DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:591)
> at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
> at com.example.pokemonkotlin.DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:588)
> at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
> at com.example.pokemonkotlin.DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:495)
> at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$1.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:100)
> at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:69)
> at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:84)
> at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:109)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:171)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:139)
> at com.example.pokemonkotlin.ui.fragments.Home.onViewCreated(Home.kt:44)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1395)
> at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7361)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3163)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)

I have tried several variations of Hilt versions, Kotlin versions, and Room versions.  And I have tried several variations of how the database is being handled with Hilt.

Here is the Hilt module providing the database:

```
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Room
import com.example.pokemonkotlin.db.PokemonDB
import com.example.pokemonkotlin.db.PokemonDao
import com.example.pokemonkotlin.utils.DB_NAME
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton


@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class DBModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePokemonDB(context: Application): PokemonDB {
        return PokemonDB.getAppDB(context)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePokeDao(pokemonDB: PokemonDB): PokemonDao {
        return pokemonDB.getPokemonDao()
    }
}
```

In the error that's given, one line that's listed above as possibly problematic is "return PokemonDB.getAppDB(context).

Here is the database file:

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.example.pokemonkotlin.model.Pokemon
import com.example.pokemonkotlin.utils.DB_NAME
import com.example.pokemonkotlin.viewmodel.PokemonViewModel

@Database(entities = [Pokemon::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class PokemonDB : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getPokemonDao(): PokemonDao

    companion object {
        private var dbINSTANCE: PokemonDB? = null

        fun getAppDB(context: Context): PokemonDB{
            if(dbINSTANCE == null) {
                dbINSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder<PokemonDB>(
                    context.applicationContext, PokemonDB::class.java, DB_NAME
                )
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return dbINSTANCE!!
        }
    }
}
```

The ".build()" line above is listed as maybe an issue.

Here is the fragment that initializes the viewmodel:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import androidx.annotation.Nullable
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.pokemonkotlin.adapters.PokemanAdapter
import com.example.pokemonkotlin.databinding.HomeBinding
import com.example.pokemonkotlin.model.Pokemon
import com.example.pokemonkotlin.viewmodel.PokemonViewModel
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class Home : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: HomeBinding? = null
    private val binding: HomeBinding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var viewModel: PokemonViewModel
    private lateinit var adapter: PokemanAdapter
    private lateinit var pokemonList: ArrayList<Pokemon>

    @Nullable
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        @Nullable container: ViewGroup?,
        @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = HomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.getRoot()
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(@NonNull view: View, @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(PokemonViewModel::class.java)

        initRecyclerView()
        setUpItemTouchHelper()
        observeData()
        viewModel.getPokemons()
    }

    private fun setUpItemTouchHelper(){
        val itemTouchHelper = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val swipedPokemonPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                val pokemon = adapter.getPokemonAt(swipedPokemonPosition)
                viewModel.insertPokemon(pokemon)
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                Toast.makeText(context, "Pokemon added to favorites.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        val swipeHelper = ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelper)
        swipeHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.pokemonRecyclerView)
    }

    private fun observeData() {
        viewModel.favoritePokemonList?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter.updateList(it);
        }
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        binding.pokemonRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        adapter = context?.let { PokemanAdapter(it, pokemonList) }!!
        binding.pokemonRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

The ViewModelProvider(this).get(PokemonViewModel::class.java) line above is listed as possibly having an issue.

Here is the project level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    ext.hilt_version = '2.40.5'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
       jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the module level build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pokemon"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    //implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0-alpha03"
    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    def room_version = "2.4.0-alpha02"
    def nav_version = "2.3.0-beta01"

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


    def activity_version = "1.3.1"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version"

    def fragment_version = "1.3.6"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.12.0"
    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.12.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'

    // Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"




    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'

    // ViewModel
    //implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0'

    // LiveData
    //implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.2.0'

    // Room
//    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    //implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    //kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    // Glide
    //implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.1'
}
```

A large part of me thinks that somehow I am not correctly implementing the Room gradle dependency correctly, but I am not sure.  I have tried quite a few ways for the Room dependency here.  There may be other problems as well.  Any help at all is appreciated!!